# Though col1 and col2 and indexes, how are duplicate entries still popping up from my table for the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a table which has 3 columns that I can see. 
`INVERTER_ID`, `TIME_STAMP` and `POWER`

`INVERTER_ID` and `TIME_STAMP` are indexes.

This is a huge table. One of my codes was throwing an error because duplicate entries were being encountered.

I got the timestamp and inverter_id for which i had duplicate entries. '2019-05-04 21:00:00' and `INV1020`

I queried the table with :

```
SELECT `INVERTER_ID`,`TIME_STAMP`,`POWER`
FROM `INV_POWER`
WHERE `TIME_STAMP`='2019-05-04 21:00:00' and
      `INVERTER_ID` ='INV1020'
```

Got only one result.

```
INV1020     2019-05-04 21:00:00     0.0
```

Strange I thought, so I went and checked the sql query my code was using and queried with the same :

```
SELECT `INVERTER_ID`,`TIME_STAMP`,`POWER
FROM `INV_POWER`
WHERE `TIME_STAMP`<='2019-05-04 21:00:01' and
      `TIME_STAMP`>='2019-05-04 21:00:00' and
       `INVERTER_ID` ='INV1020'
```

In this case i got two results:

```
INV1020     2019-05-04 21:00:00     0.0
INV1020     2019-05-04 21:00:00     0.0
```

Curious af as to how and why this happens. when i have `INVERTER_ID` and `TIME_STAMP` as indexes, i checked the structure of table and found that, 
`AUTO_INDEX` is primary_key and an index. So i queried again but this time with `AUTO_INDEX`, column in my select.

```
SELECT `AUTO_INDEX`, `INVERTER_ID`,`TIME_STAMP`,`POWER` FROM `INV_POWER` WHERE `TIME_STAMP`<='2019-05-04 21:00:01' and `TIME_STAMP`>='2019-05-04 21:00:00' and`INVERTER_ID` ='INV1020'

6081057323  INV1020     2019-05-04 21:00:00     0.0
25805384826     INV1020     2019-05-04 21:00:00     0.0
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Question: 
Why is this happening? With the index set, how did it get even inserted in the first place? Why am i seeing duplicates when i use `<` and `>`; and not when i am using `=`.

ThankYou in advance :)

Comment: what is the link you suppose may exist between an index and the duplicate entries?

Comment: please add the index descriptions.  sounds like you need a unique index

Comment: It's the milliseconds. Those timestamps have milliseconds values you are not displaying.

Comment: `INVERTER_ID and TIME_STAMP are indexes.` -- What does this even mean? Please include the index definitions you have.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect datatype of `TIME_STAMP` column allows for fractional seconds, for example, datatype could be `DATETIME(3)`. (We're just guessing here.)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

This would explain the observed behavior.